# Need some help about why this circuit (PSU) isn't working

Tags: power-supply, current-limiting, lm317

Trying to make a current limiter for my LM317 power supply. This is the complete circuit:
[image]

I found the current limiting circuit on the web, I'am powering this circuit from a 12V 20A switching lab power supply. The problem that i have is that current regulation doesn't work, voltage regulation works fine. but when i adjust the current (above 1 amp usually) the circuit completly shuts down. the 2n3055 transistors are a bit warm but that should not matter since i only wanna test if it's capable of 2 - 3 amps for maybe 2 seconds. But the circuit just dies.

If i leave it like that (dead) but still plugged in, it comes back on again after maybe 10 seconds, then shuts down again etc.

My first thought is that the LM317 overcurrent protection is kicking in, but since the transistor is taking most of the load that shouldn't matter right?

The LM317 is very cold btw. Not hot at all. My guess is that i simply forgot to add something but i can't figure out what..

I don't have any capacitors in this circuit on the breadboard, could that be the cause of the problem?

Thanks for any help in advance!

LM317 datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf

2N3055 datasheet: http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/2N3055-D.PDF

Update: I just noticed that current changes when i put a finger on the current regulation pot.. if it shows like 300 mA and i put my finger on it, it goes down to maybe 150 mA and jumps around until i remove the finger.. (Tried to change the pot but same problem occured)

Comment: A link to the original web page is probably crucial.

Comment: Well it was a youtube video actually. this is the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xE0pzvycxPc

Comment: Try posting a screen shot of the circuit. I can see one weakness that nay not be in the original.

Comment: Thanks for looking, you mean a picture of my breadboard? It will just look chaos will all the wires etc. you still want one?

Comment: 2~3A through a _breadboard_?

Comment: well, it says "max 3 amps" on the back of the board so. i guess it could handle it for a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see the 2-3 amps going through the load the lm317 is seeing a current overload situation and it is reacting to it with "Operation In Self Protection" mode. It is noted in the lm317 datasheet in section 8.4.4.

**8.4.4
Operation In Self Protection**
When an overload occurs the device will shut down Darlington NPN output stage
or reduce the output current to prevent device damage. The device will automatically reset from the overload. The output may be reduced or alternate
between on and off until the overload is removed.

You might consider putting your voltage varying circuit before the current sensing circuit. Remember your current of the entire circuit is limited to the max current of the ml317.

You need to combine both voltage and current overload together such that they
both control the 2n3055 transistor. When I find my schematic of such a circuit I will post it.

I did not see a load output of the lm317 circuit. If you are actually putting a short from the right hand 2n3055 that will be your problem.

I found that schematic:

[image: adjustable max current and voltage power supply]

Comment: Thank u, i would really appreciate if you could find the schematic.

I still don't understand how the LM317 can see an overload when the current itself doesn't go through the LM317, i thought that was the point with using power transistors. To take the load away from "other things"

Comment: Thank you for the schematic! but it uses an LM317 for the current limit and that way i can't use a pot without it heating up a lot. that's why i want a way to make the current go through a 2n3055 instead. Could you maybe give me an example of how you meant? thanks again!

Comment: What are you using for a load?  All I see is a short circuit between the emiter of the 2n3055 and ground.

Comment: I'm not using anything for a load, since it's limiting the current, would it matter if i use a load or short it?

but i have tried and used a load also and same problem occur = the circuit shuts down.

Comment: What I would do is separate the total circuit into 3 parts and test them. First I would disconnect the current sensing circuit and then test the voltage control side to see if it works with a load. Then test the current sensing circuit to see that it works. Lets us know what the outcome was.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.

I have now tried to unplug the voltage regulation part (LM317) and without it, the current limiting works fine. It can handle 3 amps pretty stable and without problem. So I'm pretty sure the problem here is that the LM317 overcurrent protection is kicking in. Do you know if there is a way to bypass the protection? I still think it's weird since not more than 100 mA is going through the LM317.

Comment: You cannot disable the over-current protection. It is built in to the lm317. Check out the diagram on page 8 of the lm317 datasheet (8.2 Functional Block Diagram). Remove that short circuit connection that is between the 2n3055 emitter and ground. Put a 1000 ohm resistor between the emitter and ground. If you are still having problems with the circuit try to contact the person that published it.

Comment: thank you very much!! I put a 1.5K resistor between emitter and ground since i didn't have a 1K available, and it went up to 2.8 amps stable without any shutdowns!

Comment: Edit: The only problem/weird thing is that the current changes when i put my finger on the pot.. any idea what might cause that?

Comment: You still have a problem. The 1.5K resistor is a load resistor for the variable voltage portion and should only be drawing .008 amps if you are using 12 volts DC at the input. Something should be getting hot. One other thing would be to put a diode between the base of the 2n3055 and the output terminal of the lm317. Install the diode with the cathode attached to the base of the 2n3055 and anode attached to the output of the lm317.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I checked if the resistor is getting hot and it's not. I'm using a 7W power resistor just in case, i can switch up to two 10W resistors if that's the case.

About the diode, Why would i need this? Is it for protection or something else?

Comment: check out this site: http://electronics-diy.com/power-supply-lm317-2n3055-0-28v-6-8a.php. He has a circuit that has current limiting and a explanation on its workings.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to simulate this circuit and it worked perfectly. But is there a way to make the current limit work even in short circuit? In short circuit the current go up to 11 amps, but it workes fine with a load.

Comment: I was also wondering if it's possible to make the current limit go lower? Following that circuit the lowest current is around 550 mA. i wanna be able to go down to 1 mA. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you get the circuit to work the way you want? If so share it with the rest of us.

Comment: I ended up using the answer you posted. It's working really well!